How do I update the Google Colab Notebook kernel? I am running an old version (0.0.1a2) and I can't update to the current version
I am running an ancient version of the Colab notebook kernel on colab.research.google.com. I’ve tried everything to update the kernel, but nothing has worked.
I am running version 0.0.1a2 (I think this is an alpha version) while the most recent version is 2.0.6!!!
I would appreciate getting help with this problem as many modules don't work properly with the antiquated notebook.
My futile attempts to update the Colab notebook kernel have consisted of:

Trying different browsers.
Clearing cache and cookies.
Restarting the Colab notebook runtime with GPU and TPU runtimes.
Pip installs colab from the notebook.
Manually install colab with the colab-0.3.2.tar.gz file. The tarball had a blank file in it.
Manually install colab from the Github Repo. That didn't work either.

enter image description here
